# Rails form for nested attributes needs to discard build if rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I#m having trouble with a form that also handles nested attributes.
The parent model "meeting" accepts nested attributes for the child model "invitation". Note it is only possible to send one invitation for a meeting, but it is optional.

The model for Meeting includes:

```
  has_one :invitation, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitation, :reject_if => proc { |a| a[:user_id].blank?  }, :allow_destroy => true
```

The problem is in the view views/meetings/_form.html.erb. I try to handle all attributes for meeting and invitation for the views new, show and edit.
Because I want a user to be able to add an invitation when there hasnt been one previously I put

```
<%= f.fields_for :invitation, @meeting.invitation ||= @meeting.build_invitation do |ff| %>
```

But this gives me an error when I want to edit the meeting and the invitation was blank (so it was rejected)
     "*Failed to save the new associated invitation.*"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You see this gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon? Simplyfy the work to me

Answer (score 0):

got it running with changing the line in  the view to

```
    <%= f.fields_for :invitation, Invitation.where(meeting_id: @meeting.id).first_or_initialize do |ff| %>
```